# Python POO: de donde sale este none?

Tags: python, poo

Estoy aprendiendo a utilizar las herencias en Python, y cuando ejecuto el código tengo el resultado que deseo, pero al final obtengo un none que no se de donde sale

```
class Human():

    def __init__(self, nombre, apellido, id, nacionalidad, pet):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.apellido = apellido
        self.id = id
        self.nacionalidad = nacionalidad
        self.pet = pet


        
    def fullName_id(self):

        print('My first name is {}, my last name is {} and my id is {}'.format(self.nombre, self.apellido, self.id))



class Empleado(Human):

    def __init__(self, salario, antiguedad, vacaciones, nombre_empleado, apellido_empleado, id_empleado, nacionalidad_empleado, pet_empleado):

         super().__init__(nombre_empleado, apellido_empleado, id_empleado, nacionalidad_empleado, pet_empleado)

         self.salario = salario
         self.antiguedad = antiguedad
         self.vacaciones = vacaciones
         

    def email_empleado(self):
        ''' Entrega la direccion de correo electronico del empleado seleccionado '''

        print('{}-{}@empresa.com'.format(self.nombre, self.apellido))

        

persona1 = Empleado('Dos mil pesos', 'cinco años', 'nunca', 'Leandro','Perez', 24242424, 'Argentino', 'Perro')

print(persona1.vacaciones)

print(persona1.email_empleado())
```

Como resultado de ejecutar ese código obtengo lo siguiente:

```
nunca
Leandro-Perez@empresa.com
None
```

Como verán obtengo un None, pero no se que línea de código lo produce

Es mi primera pregunta así que pido disculpas de antemano si es que no respeto algunas reglas de Stack, muchas gracias a todos.

Leandro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se debe a que estás haciendo 2 llamadas a `print()`. Dentro de `email_empleado` se hace una llamada a `print()` y sale la segunda línea de tu output.... pero esa llamada la hiciste *dentro* de un print:

```
print(persona1.email_empleado())
```

Así que el resultado de `email_empleado()` (que es `None`, porque no devuelves nada) se imprime. Puedes devolver un string en `email_empleado()` (sin llamar a print dentro de la función) o hacer el print dentro de la función y entonces llamarla sin print:

```
persona1.email_empleado() # sin print()
```